# Execute a Powershell script in CMD.EXE from a path with spaces

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have a ps file that I would like to execute from cmd.exe in windows server 2008 from a path with spaces.

I have the ps file in a path with blank spaces, suppose: "C:\My powershell Files"

so from within this path I need below cmd command to work when I execute:

```
c:\My powershell Files\powershell.exe %CD%\AddValuesRegistry.ps1"
```

I have powershell v2.0 so I want to it to work on this version.

I have checked below commands but without success:

```
c:\My powershell Files\powershell.exe -file '%CD%\AddValuesRegistry.ps1'
c:\My powershell Files\powershell.exe -Command "& {& '%CD%\AddValuesRegistry.ps1'}"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `%CD%`? You should invoke `powershell.exe` from its own path, and supply full path to the script like `powershell.exe -file 'c:\My powershell Files\AddValuesRegistry.ps1'`.

Comment: %CD% environment variable returns the current directory from within you execute powershell.exe command. I need to use %CD%. I know it is strange but I need to do using %CD% If you execute powershell.exe from within c:\My powershell Files, then it returns c:\My powershell Files and concatenate to it AddValuesRegistry.ps1. You obtain  c:\My powershell Files\AddValuesRegistry.ps1

Comment: And what does powershell return? "No script file" or say "script execution blocked by policy"?

Comment: I have just solved using double quotes instead of single ones and the following approach:
c:\My powershell Files\powershell.exe -file "%CD%\AddValuesRegistry.ps1"
I would like to know if this approach works for versions later than 2 as well, I mean, 3 and so on. Could someone confirm me this please?

Comment: It should work, this stuff depends on `cmd.exe` only.

Comment: Why run from cmd? Just run your script directly from the PowerShell window itself instead of running cmd.exe.